# Would use of a funnel help speed up pumping off of gases from a low to medium vacuum?

Tags: pressure, vacuum, experimental-technology

Suppose you are trying to recover gases at a pressure of a thousandth or ten thousandth of a standard atmosphere inside a closed chamber. Might it be helpful to try to create a pressure gradient by placing a funnel over the inlet to the vacuum pump, so that functionally its inlet has a larger area?

[image]